# Why is vim stripping the carriage return when I copy a line to another file?

Tags: vim

I sorted a file `a.csv` into `b.csv`.

I noticed that the sizes of the files differed, and after noticing that `b.csv` was exactly `n` bytes smaller (where `n` is the number of lines in `a.csv`), I immediately suspected that `a.csv` contained those pesky `\r`.

The `.py` script for sorting contained the line `line.strip()` which removed the carriage returns and then `afile.write(line2 + '\n')` which wrote newlines but not carriage returns.

*Ok. Makes sense.*

The strange bit is that when I `vim`'d `a.csv`, I didn't see the `^M` like I usually do (maybe the reason lies in a configuration file), so I only found out about the `\r` from opening the file in a hex editor.

The more interesting bit, is that I would take a small subset of `a.csv` (`3y`) and paste it to a testfile (`p`).

Sorting the testfile resulted in a file of the exact same size as the original.

From `xxd`ing, I see that there is no `\r` in the new testfile.

**When I yank a line that contains a carriage return and paste it into another file, the pasted line does not contain the carriage return. Why?**

I tested this on Windows (Cygwin), and it does appear to copy the `\r`. But on the Linux machine I'm using, it doesn't.

How come?

**Edit:**

I tried reproducing the issue on another linux machine, but I couldn't. It appears to be a configuration thing - some file somewhere telling vim to do that.

Comment: Try `:help fileformats`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim's model of a loaded file is a sequence of lines, each consisting of a sequence of characters. In this model, newlines aren't themselves characters. So when you're copying lines of text, you're not copying the CRs or LFs. Vim also stores a number of other pieces of information which are used to write the file back out again, principally:

`fileformat` can be `unix`, `dos` or `mac`. This determines what end-of-line character will be written at the end of each line.

`endofline` can be on or off. This determines if the last line of the file has an end-of-line character.

`bomb` can be on or off. This determines if a byte order mark is written at the start of the first line.

`fileencoding` specifies what character encoding will be used to store the file, such as `utf-8`.

Normally these are all auto-detected upon loading the file. In particular, `fileformat` will be auto-detected depending on the settings in `fileformats` option, which may be configured differently on different platforms. However, sometimes things can go wrong. The most common problem is that a file might have mixed line-endings, and that's when you'll start seeing `^M` floating around. In this case, Vim has loaded the file as if it's in unix format - it treated the LFs as the line separators and the CRs as just normal characters. You can see which mode Vim has opened the file in by entering `:set fileformat?` or just `set ff?` for short.

Comment: If I open a Windows file in Vim, I can't actually search CR and LF using their hex code because they are not in the buffer, right?

Answer (score 4):

Vim detects the newline style (Windows CR-LF vs. Unix LF) when *opening* the file (according to the `'fileformats'` option), and uses the detected `'fileformat'` value for all subsequent saves. So, the newline style is a property of the Vim buffer / opened file. When you yank line(s) from one buffer and paste it into another, the newline style isn't kept; instead, the newline style of the target buffer is used, as this makes much more sense.